# How merge a collection of associative arrays?

Tags: laravel, collections

Consider

```
$c = collect([['name' => 'Joe'], ['score' => 98]])
$c->flatten(1)
```

which gives

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1153
     all: [
       "Joe",
       98,
     ],
   }
```

Which is not what I expected. I would expect it to combine them to get the following:

```
[
    'name' => "Joe",
    'score' =>   98,
]
```

How can I do that? Preferably with a collection method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Collection::collapse()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-collapse) might be the method you're looking for:

```
$c = collect([['name' => 'Joe'], ['score' => 98]]);
$c->collapse();
```

which results in an array like this:

```
[
  "name" => "Joe",
  "score" => 98,
]
```